# Preventing re-renders using memo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-memo

Consider:

```js
import { useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube'
import { id2url } from './utils/format';

const Player = ({url}) => {
    console.log('Player re-renders')          // I should only see this once, right?
    return (
        <div className='PlayerInnerWrapper'>
            <ReactPlayer
                className="Player"
                url={url}
                controls={true}
                width='100%'
                height='100%' />
        </div>
    )
}

const MemoizedPlayer = memo(Player, (prev, cur) => {
    return true;                              // Player should never re-render, right?
});

const Parent = ({ videoData, setters }) => {
    useEffect(()=>{setters.setTerms([...setters.terms, 'aa'])})

    return (
        <div className="SecondRow">
            <div className='PlayerOuterWrapper'>
                <MemoizedPlayer url={id2url(videoData.id)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For this experiment, `useEffect` in `Parent` purposefully causes `Parent` to infinitely re-render. My problem is that the console output shows that `Player` re-renders on each re-render of `Parent`. Note that `Parent` uses the memoized version of `Player` and that the second argument of `memo` is the function that always returns `true`, which means to never re-render. So, why does `Player` get re-rendered?

Comment: Is Player rendering twice, or infinite times? If twice, that's because of `<StrictMode/>`. If infinite times, my guess would be that `Parent` is unmounting and remounting, but the cause of that would be something above Parent (which i don't have access to).

Comment: @NicholasTower Infinite times. In the parent of `Parent`, `setters` is returned by a hook defining `terms` as a state (using `useState`). How would updating `terms` cause unmounting rather than re-render of the parent of `Parent`?

Comment: ["React may still re-render it: memoization is a performance optimization, not a guarantee."](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#memo)

Comment: `How would updating terms cause unmounting rather than re-render of the parent of Parent?` Some examples: a `key` could be changing, or a component type could be getting re-created on each render. If you'd like to test whether it's unmounting (after all, i'm just making an educated guess and could be wrong), try adding this to Parent: `useEffect(() => { return () => console.log('unmounting') }, [])`. Strict mode can cause that to log once, but logging repeatedly indicates a problem.

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes, it is indeed unmounting...